# How can I pass variable in javascript without using parameter?

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters

I have one function using to get data from text file and alert it in another function.

```
  var library_name; // Global Variable

  function getLibraryName(){
         jQuery.get('stream.txt', function(data) {
           library_name = data.toString().substring(17,data.length);
         });
  }

 function saveFeedback() {
    alert(library_name);
  }
```

When saveFeedback is called, it will alert library_name

I have been tried to put it in the same function like this

```
function saveFeedback() {
    jQuery.get('stream.txt', function(data) {
         library_name = data.toString().substring(17,data.length);
    });

    alert(library_name);
}
```

but it is still keep saying undefined in console

How to solve this out? Without using parameter because saveFeedback function has to be called from somewhere else.

Comment: Use something like `jQuery.get().success(function() { alert(); });`, because the request didnt complete yet when it reaches the alert code. So you'll have to wait until you have an answer from the request.

Comment: the alert will happen before the ajax call is completed because its ajax, asynch. You can add a .success() chained method for your alert.

Comment: All this answering questions in comments is bizarre and not really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to `.get` is called when the get finishes. You're saying, "fetch `stream.txt` and when it finishes, execute this function". The following calls saveFeedback when the get is finished:

```
function getLibraryName(){
         jQuery.get('stream.txt', function(data) {
           library_name = data.toString().substring(17,data.length);
           saveFeedback();
         });
  }
```

Because get is asynchronous, your interpreter will instantiate the `saveFeedback` function before the `success` function is called (although some sanity checkers like JSLint probably want you to define `saveFeedback` before `getLibraryName`.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use saveFeedback() function in $.get(data) callback, because it it async request and you do not know, when it will be completed.

Comment: I have tried sir but it crashed, my other parts of code won't work anymore.

Comment: IMHO, you should not use that code before GET request is loaded. I would advise to to change script logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a hidden input field and attach data to it using $.data();

For example:

```
  function getLibraryName(){
         jQuery.get('stream.txt', function(data) {
           var library_name = data.toString().substring(17,data.length);
           $('#myHiddenField').data('library_name', library_name);
         });
  }

 function saveFeedback() {
    alert($('#myHiddenField').data('library_name'));
  }
```

Comment: Why would you use a hidden form field!?!? That is bonkers, and furthermore doesn't even answer the OP's actual question. He's already successful in passing the value around using two functions; he wants to know how to do it with one. You didn't answer that question, instead you proposed a completely different and needless way to accomplish the thing that is already working...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `get` initiates an asynchronous call. Asynchronous means that the result from it will return *later*... maybe a short time later, maybe many seconds later. After kicking off this call, the code then proceeds immediately to the next line which is your alert. This alert occurs *before* the return from the asynchronous call, so of course the variable is still `undefined`--it hasn't been set yet.

One way to solve the problem might be to tell jQuery to make the call synchronous. But this is the wrong answer because it will stop the browser from responding to user interaction while the call is occurring. Instead, you need to adjust how you think about asynchronous calls. The basic concept is that instead of having a big function that does things step by step like a normal, procedural recipe (do step 1, then step 2, then step 3), instead you have to set up two different recipes or pieces of code: one to initiate the ajax call and then **exit**, and one to respond to the result of the ajax call.

Now, you already have two functions. You can't combine them for the reasons I already explained. But, you can chain them, or encapsulate one inside the other:

```
var library_name;

function saveFeedback() {
   alert(library_name);
}

function getLibraryName(){
   jQuery.get('stream.txt', function(data) {
      library_name = data.toString().substring(17 ,data.length);
      saveFeedback(); // this chains the two functions together
   });
}
```

or maybe even better:

```
var library_name;

function saveFeedback() {
   alert(library_name);
}

function receiveLibraryName(data) {
   library_name = data.toString().substring(17, data.length);
   saveFeedback();
   // additional statements here after saving
}

function getLibraryName(){
   jQuery.get('stream.txt', receiveLibraryName);
}
```

The point is that you *cannot* continue in the next statement as usual within the `getLibraryName` function. The steps you wish to take after the ajax call *must* be inside of another function: either in the callback function itself, or in another function called from the callback function.

Comment: Which of my two examples is saying undefined? Did you copy and paste it intact? Are you sure library_name is being set properly? Use Firebug in Firefox or the console in Chrome, and put `console.log(data)` in the callback function from the ajax request, and inspect its contents. Is it what you expected? Once you reply I will try to help you again.

Comment: Your 2 examples are saying undefined sir. I didn't copy and paste. I'm sure that library_name is being set properly. The data in console is what I'm expected.

Comment: No need to call me sir! You're going to have to post your non-working code. Perhaps a jsfiddle would be best...

Comment: I can't, there's a lot of code involved. You may need to see my whole project.

Comment: What I've shared should work. There must be something else going on.  You don't have `library_name` declared in more than one place, do you?

Comment: I have sure I have declared it once. :)

Comment: Without more code I don't know how I can help more. Please try to work up a jsfiddle.net example.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
var library_name;
function getLibraryName(){
     jQuery.get('stream.txt', function(data) {
       let lbName= data.toString().substring(17,data.length);
       saveFeedback(lbName);
  });
}

function saveFeedback(lbName) {
   library_name = lbName; //If you are using library_name in other code
   alert(library_name);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to define library_name before jquery.get once. Because if the jquery.get doesnt work library_name will not be created by the time u call alert.
please add
    var library_name;
as the first line of saveFeedback().

Comment: This is completely incorrect information. Adding `var library_name` will NOT do as you say.